# How to handle compliments?

Tags: discussion

Since I joined the community few months ago, I see a lot of questions where the OP is using a language full of gratitude and thanks in advance to the degree that the desperation is almost cringing. But because the community is new and most users come here from different backgrounds (developers, enthusiasts, hobbyists, futurist, etc.), it makes perfect sense.

But nonetheless, 'thanks', 'thanks in advance', etc. questions and comments for 'trivial' questions doesn't appear helpful.

How should one handle it? Should I just tell them it's okay and that we are here for professional questions and answers and there's no need to do so? Or it's only me?

Comment: Related: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and ["comment everywhere" privilege](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 3):

An efficient way would be to submit an edit to the question that tightens it up.  (Some stackoverflow questions have been tightened over time, for example https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1642028/revisions)